# Code cant read the document that has a studentID field

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the studentID string field in each of the documents of my Students Collection

```
Future<Student> fetchStudentDetails(String studentID, String subjectID) async {
    try {
      // Replace this with your actual code to fetch student details from Firestore
      DocumentSnapshot studentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Students')
          .doc(studentID)
          .get();

      if (studentSnapshot.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic>? studentData = studentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;

        if (studentData != null) {
          // Check if assessments for the specified subject exist
          Map<String, dynamic>? subjectAssessments = studentData['Assessments'][subjectID];
          if (subjectAssessments != null) {
            return Student(assessments: {subjectID: subjectAssessments});
          } else {
            print('Assessments for subject $subjectID not found for student $studentID');
          }
        } else {
          print('Student data is null for student $studentID');
        }
      } else {
        print('Document not found for studentID: $studentID');
      }

      // Return an empty Student object if data is not found
      return Student(assessments: {});
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
      print('Error fetching student details: $error');
      return Student(assessments: {});
    }
  }




  Future<void> _initializeGradeModel() async {
    try {
      // Fetch student details
      Student student = await fetchStudentDetails(widget.studentID, widget.subjectID);
```

It just print "Document not found for studentID: $studentID."
Any things i needed to change?

I tried Querysnapshot but it loads infinitely.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of the document you're reading.  Without that, we can't tell how this code is going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the studentID string field in each of the documents of my
> Students Collection

Is that the `studentId` the same as the ***document's id***? If not, that is your issue. Your code is querying the id of the document, and not the studentId field on the document.

```
DocumentSnapshot studentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('Students')
   .doc(studentID) // <-- this needs to be the document id and not a field on the document
   .get();
```

You can perform a query on fields within a document using the query function:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

```dart
// Create a reference to the students collection
final studentsRef = db.collection("Students");

// Create a query against the collection.
final query = studentsRef.where("studentId", isEqualTo: studentId);
```